# can 2 unity objects' script get each others' variables? {ANSWERED}

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 unity objects, each attached with a script. the scripts is set up so that they read from each other variables, and then then react accordingly.

The issue is that only one of the scripts can read the other's variables and act on it, while the other is unable to do the same, instead saying that it does not exist even though I have assigned it in the inspector

Is this a limitation of unity?

**scriptA**

```
public GameObject Player;
    Animator animator;
    scriptB player;
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();//animations are all set up
    player = Player.GetComponent<scriptB>();
}
public bool leftpunch = false;
public bool rightpunch = false;

if (player.lowleftpunch|| player.lowrightpunch|| player.highleftpunch|| player.highrightpunch)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("block");
    }
```

**scriptB**<--unity apparently cannot see script A with this, despite being assigned correctly in the inspector

```
public GameObject opponet;
acriptA AI;
Animator animator;
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();//anmations all all set up
   // AI = opponet.GetComponent<acriptA>();
}
public bool lowleftpunch=false;
public bool lowrightpunch = false;
public bool highleftpunch = false;
public bool highrightpunch = false;
public bool isEvade = false;

if (isEvade==true && iframes> 0){
        iframes -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        isEvade = false;
    }
    if (AI.leftpunch==true||AI.rightpunch==true)
    {
        if (isEvade == false)
        {
            if (AI.leftpunch==true)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger("hit left");
            }else if(AI.rightpunch== true)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger("hit right");
            }
        }else if (isBlocking == true)
        {

        }
    }
```

EDIT:
right I am dumb
somehow unity decided to assign 2 of the same script B to object B, which means that they are stopping from each other from working.

Comment: Is this all your code? You never assign the `Player`/`opponent` variables...GetComponent won't work on a null reference

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're doing.  In ScriptB, you get component Animator but I'm assuming the Animator is assigned in the Inspector. (Can't tell, you're code is really terse - Maybe it's [SerializedField] ?).  In ScriptA, what is Player? (Capital P)

Comment: sorry, due to UNI rules, I am unable to share a vast majority of my code, since they have some sort of checker to check copied work.But I see if I can increase the size first. the animator is both assigned correctly and without issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetComponent is used on a gameObject to get at one of the scripts assigned to it in the inspector. So if you have a script Example1 attached to one gameOBject:

```
public class Example1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string customMessage = "Hi there.";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

}
```

And another gameObject with Example2 attached:

```
public class Example2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject otherGameObject;

    Example1 example1Component; 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //gets script instance from gameObject;
        example1Component = otherGameObject.GetComponent<Example1>();

        //reads message from variable on script instance
        Debug.Log(example1Component.customMessage);
    }

}
```

That will access the variables from the other script. Alternately, you can make your custom variable the Type of the other script and when you drag it into the unity inspector, it references that script directly. and any public variable can also be accessed simply. like so:

```
public class Example2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //already referencing other script
    public Example1 otherComponent; 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //reads message from variable on script instance
        Debug.Log(otherComponent.customMessage);
    }

}
```

Comment: what I need is to have 2 scripts to "read"each other, which unity seems to be incapale of

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not a limitation of Unity.

Try serializing direct references to the types of scripts you want to access instead of serializing `GameObjects`.

```C#
public class ClassA : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ClassB _classB = default;
    [SerializeField] private string _message = "Message from ClassA";

    private void Start()
    {
        // Will print the value assigned in the inspector for the component
        // of ClassB.
        Debug.Log(_classB.GetValue());
    }

    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return _message;
    }
}

public class ClassB : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ClassA _classA = default;
    [SerializeField] private float _value = 3.14f;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Will print the message assigned in the inspector for the component
        // of ClassA.
        Debug.Log(_classA.GetMessage());
    }

    public float GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Without seeing your error message, and without seeing your full code, it would appear that `GetComponent<T>()` is failing for one of a few reasons:

1. The `GameObject` isn't assigned in the inspector.
2. The `GameObject` assigned in the inspector doesn't have the component you are trying to get.

In both cases, you'll see a `NullReferenceException` message in the Console window.